# How to create array column based on unique values in another column SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, coalesce, array-agg

I have data from a postgres tables that looks like this:

```
Server    |    Database    | Contact 

server1   |    db1         | contact 1
server1   |    db2         | contact 2
server1   |    db3         | contact 3 
server2   |    db1         | contact 4
server2   |    db2         | contact 3
```

But I need to transform it to pass to a front end view in this format:

```
Server    | Database        | Contact 

server1   | {db1, db2, db3} | {contact1, contact2, contact3}
server2   | {db1, db2}      | {contact3, contact4}
```

For every unique value in the `Server` column I want to create an array column out of every other column in my SQL query.  So far I have something like this but it does not seem to create an array out of the `Server` column (Contact column excluded for clarity):

```
SELECT     "table1"."Server"
            COALESCE( NULLIF( array 
           ( 
                  select DISTINCT x 
                  FROM   unnest( array_agg(DISTINCT "table1"."Server") ) x 
                  WHERE  x IS NOT NULL ), '{}' ), '{"No Data"}' ) AS "serverList" , 
           COALESCE( NULLIF( array 
           ( 
                  SELECT x 
                  FROM   unnest( array_agg(DISTINCT "table1"."Database") ) x 
                  WHERE  x IS NOT NULL ), '{}' ), '{"No Data"}' ) AS "databseList"
FROM       "table1"                                     
GROUP BY   
           "table1"."Server"
```

How can I correctly create array columns out of unique entries in the Server column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `array_agg()`?

```
select server, array_agg(database) as databases, array_agg(contact) as contacts
from t
group by server;
```

If the values need to be unique in the arrays, use `distinct`.

Comment: how about distinct `database` and get corresponding `contact`. meaning `len(database) == len(contact)` in selecte result.